# In Rails ActiveRecord, how can I ignore selecting "duplicate" records that have a difference in only one of the columns?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I have very little SQL experience and I'm still quite new to Rails.  In Rails 3, In my "Report" model, I am currently querying a database with a line like this:

```
MyRecord.where('org_id=?', self.org_id).order('vehicle_id')
```

Such a query is producing records like these (obviously I changed the data a little):

```
151 Accord 214  115,386 Mule    n/a SammyExample
152 Accord 214  115,386 Mule    n/a SammyExample
140 Camry       55,555  Foghorn n/a SammyExample
```

Let's call that first column "MyRecord_ID".

Now, I want to be able to perform a query that would leave out duplicates but WITHOUT considering the MyRecord_ID column.  In other words, the first two records above would be considered duplicates and one of them would be left out.  How would I do this?

Also, as a side note, I don't understand why the MyRecord's have ID's (that are accessible via MyRecord.id) and yet there is no MyRecord_ID column in the schema.rb file.

Thank you.  All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: well there is no MyRecord_ID in the schema, since rails will create that by default, unless you pass `id: false` to create_table.  if you are pulling them through an association, you can look at the uniq: true action for has_many. Else you are going to need to use SELECT DISTINCT.. but the format for it is slightly different depending upon what Database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
MyRecord.where('org_id=?', self.org_id).order('vehicle_id').group(:vehicle_id)
```

If you are selecting Vehicles, you may want to flip it.

```
Vehicle.include(:my_record).where(...).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the id in result set, use select()

```
MyRecord.select("distinct [cols you want]").where('org_id=?', self.org_id).order('vehicle_id')
```